# Why does Giggle ignore more than .gitignore?

Tags: git

This is a question about why Giggle acts in a certain way.

### Reproduce

To reproduce what my question is about you need to have git and Giggle installed. Step 4–10 is not necessary to reproduce. I added them to illustrate git workflow.

1. `mkdir test` – Make a directory for testing.
2. `cd test`
3. `git init` – Initialize a git project.
4. `echo -e '/*\n!*.tex' > .gitignore` – Create a .gitignore file.
5. `echo -e "test" > test.tex` – Write something to test.tex.
6. `git add .`
7. `git commit -m "First commit"` – Commit what's written to test.tex.
8. `echo -e "\test" >> test.tex` – Write something more to test.tex.
9. `git add .`
10. `git commit -m "Second commit"` – Commit what's written to test.tex.
11. Check the project in Giggle. There is no file to be viewed in the project:
    [image: No file to be viewed in the project in Giggle]
12. `rm .gitignore`
13. Update the project in Giggle (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Now the file can viewed:
    [image: The file can viewed in Giggle]

### My question

Why can't the files be viewed when the .gitignore file is there (step 11)? It should not be due to the .gitignore file. The content of the .gitignore file is:

```
/*
!*.tex
```

The first line means ignore all. The second line means don't ignore all .tex files. So test.tex should not be ignored. `man gitignore` says

> An optional prefix !  which negates
>   the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will
>   become included again.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it is a bug in the program. Perhaps [GNOME Bug # 575018](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=575018). I've added you're test case to the report.